# how to add vpcconfig section in lambda cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

To be able to connect with internet, I want to add vpcconfig section in my lambda using cloudformation template. AWS has given one example of how to connect lambda with VPC [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-vpcconfig.html) . But my requirement is little bit extended. I have exported subnet ids and security group id in export section from other template and from there i have to import the same in my lambda template. to do that first i am adding its key in parameter section of lambda template and then follow the process mentioned in mentioned url above.

My code is like :
in parameter section of lambda template :

```
Parameters:
 SecurityGroupId:
   Description: |-
     VPC security group id
   Type:String
   Default: 'sg-importkey'
SubnetId1:
   Description: |-
     Subnet id 1
   Type:String
   Default: 'sb1-importkey'
SubnetId2:
   Description: |-
     Subnet id 2
   Type:String
   Default: 'sb2-importkey'
```

Then in properties section of lambda function, added following vpcsection:

```
VpcConfig:
  SecurityGroupIds: !ImportValue
    'fn::sub': 'SecurityGroupId'
  SubnetIds: !importValue
    'fn::sub': 'SubnetId1'
    'fn::sub': 'SubnetId2'
```

getting error while deploying:
"Properties validation failed for resource function with message:#/VpcConfig/SecurityGroupsIds: expected type: JSONArray, found:String"

Answer (score 0):

`SecurityGroupsIds` must be a **list**, not a string:

```
VpcConfig:
  SecurityGroupIds: 
     - Fn::ImportValue:
         !Sub "${SecurityGroupId}"
  SubnetIds: 
     - Fn::ImportValue:
         !Sub "${SubnetId1}"
     - Fn::ImportValue:
         !Sub "${SubnetId2}"
```

Same for `SubnetIds`.